# import maven web project in myeclipse error with subversion plugin

Tags: maven-3, myeclipse

when i import a web project builded by maven from my local disk,myeclipse(version 10.7.1)
happened to tell that maven build  error ,the error description is "No marketplace entries found to handle svn-revision-number-maven-plugin:1.13:revision in Eclipse."

i can't post a shorcut of this problem because of the number of reputation.

howerver,please